# Azure Blob Storage Containers as a dropdownlist items

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to display the azure blob storage containers name as a items of the DropDownList. I want to do this using ASP.NET and MVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the WindowsAzure.Storage nuget package the following code should get you the list of containers from blob storage:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   // User your connection string in place of connectionString.
   var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);

   // Create the blob client.
   var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

   // Get the list of containers from blob storage.
   var containers = blobClient.ListContainers();

   // Generate a MVC SelectList from the list of containers.
   var listForView  = new SelectList(containers, "Name", "Name");

   // You can now attach this to your existing view model or just put it in a ViewBag and use it from there on your view
   ViewBag.ContainersList = listForView;

   return View();
}
```

From here on you can pass the select list you created via ViewBag or your view model to your View and then you can use it with the DropDownList helper.